# Quotient program help me

Tags: c++

Hi i have problem with c++

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <cstdlib>  

using namespace std;  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
  float a,b,wynik;  

  cout << "quotient" << endl   
       << "..." << endl << endl   
       << "quotient 2 numbers."  
       << "\ndivisior does not equal 0"<< endl << endl;  

  cout << "a=";  
  cin >> a;  

  cout << "b=";  
  cin >> b;  


  if (b!=0)  
      cout << "\n" << a << " / " << b << " = " << a/b << "\n\n";  
  else  
    cout <<"\ndivisior does not equal 0!\n\n";  

  system("PAUSE");    
  return 0;  
}
```

I must use for or while when someone try quotient number by 0.

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Replace the `if` with a `while` and correct the source code. Enable all warnings and debugging information (perhaps compile with `g++ -Wall -g`). Learn to use a debugger (maybe `gdb`).

Comment: *"Replace the `if` with a `while`" -- wouldn't this just create an infinite loop when `b != 0`?

Comment: @KamilBest How is it "not working" ? What happens ? You can add cout statements or use a debugger to follow the execution of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you probably want to ask for input again if `b` is zero

You can have something like this :

```
do {

  cout << "quotient" << endl   
       << "..." << endl << endl   
       << "quotient 2 numbers."  
       << "\ndivisior does not equal 0"<< endl << endl;  

  cout << "a=";  
  cin >> a;  

  cout << "b=";  
  cin >> b;  

  if (b!=0)  
      cout << "\n" << a << " / " << b << " = " << a/b << "\n\n";  
  else  
    cout <<"\ndivisior does not equal 0!\n\n";  
}while(b==0);
```

Comment: Yes, but it still does not work..  http://scr.hu/1u1j/rp2c5

Comment: @KamilBest then might be doing it wrong See [here](http://ideone.com/HS5iLR)

Answer (score 0):

Your terms are wrong, see [Wikipedia definition of "quotient"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient).

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    char   prompt[] =
        "\n"
        "Division, dividend / divisor = quotient:\n"
        "    Enter divisior: ";
    int divisior;
    int dividend;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::cin >> divisor;
        if (divisor == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n* Divisor is zero, try again.\n";
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "\n    Enter dividend: ";
        std::cin >> dividend;
        std::cout << "\nResult of "
                  << dividend
                  << " / "
                  << divisor
                  << " is, using integer division, "
                  << dividend / divisor
                  << "\n";
        break;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```